# Finding the absolute maximum and minimum within an interval?

Tags: calculus

For some arbitrary function: $f(x)$ within the interval $a<x<b$, should I just calculate the roots for $f'(x)$, and the points $f(a)$ & $f(b)$, and make deductions based around what is going on at those points, or is there some more rigorous or arithmetic method?

Thank you

Comment: good points, thanks.

Comment: That is the rigorous way, test critical points and the endpoints.  The "deductions" are whatever point is the maximum and minimum, respectively.

Comment: Is there some trick using tangents and secant lines or something more impressive?

Comment: You should also test the supremum/infimum at the endpoints.

Comment: You really mean "For some arbitrary differentiable function".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you are approaching this problem correctly. Just in case there is any confusion, you do know that:

If $f'(x) \neq 0$ for any $x \in (a,b)$ then the max/min of $f$ on $(a,b)$ is determined strictly by $f(a)$ and $f(b)$.

If $f'(x) = 0$ for some $x$ in the interval, well, you'll have to do some analysis on $f$. There is no way to tell what's going on if $f$ is just arbitrary, *and* you aren't also assuming things like $f$ is monotone increasing/decreasing, constant, periodic, etc. I'm even assuming that $f$ is differentiable as I type based on your calculus tag. If $f$ is differentiable on $(a,b)$ then the max/min of $f$ on $(a,b)$ is simply $\min\{f(a),\space f(b),\space f(x_1),\space \ldots, \space f(x_n)\}$ and $\max\{f(a),\space f(b),\space f(x_1),\space \ldots, \space f(x_n)\}$ respectively, where $f'(x_1) = f'(x_2) = \ldots = f'(x_n) = 0$. If you don't get to assume $f$ is  differentiable I don't think there's much you can say.

Comment: For the first point: $f'(x) \neq x \in (a,b)$, does this go back to a specific theorem?

Comment: @Julian73 I'm just stating that from my personal intuition :p But I'm pretty sure you can force it out using the Extreme Value Theorem and a little finagling https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extreme_value_theorem